# PostgreSQL error: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)

Tags: postgresql

I have the following problem when trying to create and connect an PostgreSQL server:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5678? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5678?
```

I tried many possible solutions, but I think I'm missing something else.

My folder "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data" is empty and in the Windows service app the service "postgresql-x64-12" does not exist.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The original error message says (in German):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>initdb -U postgres -W C:\Users\woelf\PostgreSQLData
Die Dateien, die zu diesem Datenbanksystem gehören, werden dem Benutzer
»woelf« gehören. Diesem Benutzer muss auch der Serverprozess gehören.

Der Datenbankcluster wird mit der Locale »German_Germany.1252« initialisiert werden.
Die Standarddatenbankkodierung wurde entsprechend auf »WIN1252« gesetzt.
Die Standardtextsuchekonfiguration wird auf »german« gesetzt.

Datenseitenprüfsummen sind ausgeschaltet.

Geben Sie das neue Superuser-Passwort ein:
Geben Sie es noch einmal ein:

berichtige Zugriffsrechte des bestehenden Verzeichnisses C:/Users/woelf/PostgreSQLData ... ok
erzeuge Unterverzeichnisse ... ok
wähle Implementierung von dynamischem Shared Memory ... windows
wähle Vorgabewert für max_connections ... Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
20
wähle Vorgabewert für shared_buffers ... Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
400kB
wähle Vorgabewert für Zeitzone ... CET
erzeuge Konfigurationsdateien ... ok
führe Bootstrap-Skript aus ... Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Kindprozess hat mit Code 1 beendet
initdb: entferne Inhalt des Datenverzeichnisses »C:/Users/woelf/PostgreSQLData«
```

The error message when I set my system language to english says:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>initdb -U postgres -W C:\Users\woelf\PostgreSQLData
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "woelf".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "English_United States.1252".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "WIN1252".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

Enter new superuser password:
Enter it again:

fixing permissions on existing directory C:/Users/woelf/PostgreSQLData ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... windows
selecting default max_connections ... The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
20
selecting default shared_buffers ... The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
400kB
selecting default time zone ... CET
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... The system cannot find the path specified.
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "C:/Users/woelf/PostgreSQLData"
```

Comment: Either the server isn't started at the host and port you specified, or `listen_addresses` is not configured to listen at the network interface, or a firewall blocks you.

Comment: Its very likely that i didnt started the server, but i just startet to learn SQL and databases, so i dont know how to start the server.

Comment: That depends on your operating system and how you installed PostgreSQL. You can always start it manually using `pg_ctl`, as detailed in the documentation.

Comment: I tried `pg_ctl status`. I realised i have no Path to a DB or Server. I think I'm still missing an important step.

Comment: Look up `initdb`. It creates a data directory.

Comment: It runs until it trys to run the Bootstrap-Script. Ends with "Code 1" and deletes everything again. Also there are many messages like "The system cannot find the given Path".       This prompts also when i run python scripts, but they run anyway so i ignored them.

Comment: Without knowing the error message, there is little I can say.

Comment: I tried init DB with different settings and usern but the error always shows up.

Comment: Did you specify `-U postgres` with `initdb`? If not, try that.

Comment: yes, I tried `initdb -U postgres -W [Path]`, but the same error shows up.

Comment: I guess somebody would have to have a look at your machine. I cannot guess what the problem might be.

Comment: You were right. After factory resetting my machine it all works without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue where localhost was pointing to `::0` instead of `127.0.0.1` and it was caused by a file that was saved at the directory where I ran the command. The solution is to delete that generated file and rerun.

1. Run `ls -l` at the directory where you executed the command.

[image]

2. Delete the generated file(s) `rm jumpserver-connect*`.

Comment: Thanks! it was probably something like this, because i factory reset my pc (not because of Postgres) and then it worked.